# How to fix GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql script with GROUP_CONCAT

```
  SELECT msg_id, uid_fk, message, message_type,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT message_type
          SEPARATOR ';' ) 
 FROM messages
 WHERE status = '1'
```

GROUP_CONCAT message_type returns (A;B;A;C;) as wanted. Now i want to put a condition an if saying

```
   if(message_type == 'A')   
   {
      do that......
   }
   elseif(message_type == 'B')
   {
      do this......
   }
```

but all i am getting is the first value of message_type

Comment: Can you provide an sqlfiddle?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fff96/1

Comment: Look at my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fff96/4 Do you want case analysis in MySQL or you do it in programming language?

Comment: In programming language i want to make a condition. If (types=='A') { do this } else if(types=='B'){ do that ... }. So i guess the right way should be to give a different name? like this? FROM messages AS messages1) AS types

Comment: Did you look at the code in my fiddle?

Comment: yes sorry i edited my comment

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want. If you want to compare a type, use type column. Why do you need GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: OK let me be clear. This is a complete fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5d62/7 i need groupconcat i think because i want to return all type_upload. A msg_id can have different type_upload so i want to make an if type_upload=='AB' do this else do that. but i am getting the first type_upload e.g. 'A'

Comment: do i need a for each after sql statement?

Comment: Remove group_concat. It groups the rows for you. And because of that you get only 1 value of type_upload.

Comment: i did. it only returns the first value. Do i need to put a for each

Comment: And i have to put a GROUP_BY because multiple times the same message as times as type_upload

Comment: "i have to put a GROUP_BY because multiple times the same message as times as type_upload " - I don't understand what you want to say here. Can you pub a table with sample data in the question and show us the ideal result you want to get?

Comment: The fiddle is quite clear. Maybe i don't express myself like i want to. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5d62/9 So, in this fiddle you ll see that with GROUP_BY it returns one result as wanted. But the type_upload is only A. If you remove the GROUP_BY you ll see four results. Now i want to make an if (type_upload =='AB'){DO THIS///} ELSEIF(type_upload =='A'){///do that}. So i have to have as result all type_upload right?

Comment: And if i dont put the GROUP_BY then it will display all 4 messages and i dont want that. I want the one message with the same msg_id but to have all type_uploads as results.